# Google Map Api ServiceNotAvailable

Tags: android, maps

i read more arcticle in this site about this problem but my problem persists.
My MANIFEST contains this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```

But when i call this function of my MapsActivity:

```
private String getAddress(double latitudine, double longitudine) throws IOException{

    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.ITALIAN);
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitudine, longitudine, 10);

    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
    String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);


    return address + ", " + city+ ", "+ country;
}
```

I receive this exception:
12-05 12:49:01.500: W/System.err(26206): java.io.IOException: Service not Available

I not use emulator....

Please help me is very important...

Comment: Don't worry. Sometimes it happen. Try later.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the mapid given from the google map api ?Also check whether the WiFi and GPS are enabled in your device.Also the permissions should be outside the  tag in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.... 
When you try to retrieve a coordinate without address(for example private area) it's return an IOException.... Why???? it's an error?